# NTLM authentication fails with .NET 6 (LDAP error 53), succeeds with .NET 4.7.2

Tags: node.js, .net, .net-core, ldap, ntlm

In the client we are using the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) with the [UseDefaultCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usedefaultcredentials?view=net-6.0) option to authenticate against a Node.js server running [express-nltm](https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm). The authentication is done using NTLM and `express-nltm` is communicating with an Active Directory server over LDAPS.

The client is compiled against `.NET Standard 2.0`. If `.NET 4.7.2` is used as runtime everything works fine. However, if the same assembly is executed with `.NET 6.0.4` the authentication fails since the the Active Directory server returns the error code `53 - unwilling to perform`.

The authentication fails at the last step of the NTLM flow. It may be relevant that the first 58 bytes of the `Authorization` header sent by the client are equal for `.NET 4.7.2` and `.NET 6` except for bytes `51` and `53`, so something seems to be done differently by `.NET 6` in comparison to `.NET 4.7.2`. Additionally, the issue only occurs if the communication to the Active Directory is done over `LDAPS`. It works fine in case `LDAP` is used.

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .NET 4.7.2 | 78 | 84 | 76 | 77 | 83 | 83 | 80 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 130 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 24 | 0 |
| .NET 6 | 78 | 84 | 76 | 77 | 83 | 83 | 80 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 130 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24 | 0 | 24 | 0 |

|  | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .NET 4.7.2 | 154 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 88 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 108 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 114 | 0 |
| .NET 6 | 154 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 88 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 108 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 16 | 0 | 114 | 0 |

|  | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .NET 4.7.2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 178 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| .NET 6 | 0 | 0 | **16** | 0 | **16** | 0 | 178 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

So the questions would be

- Has anything changed in the NTLM implementation between `.NET 4.7.2` and `.NET 6`?
- What is the significance of bytes `51` and `53` in the Authorization header?